# How to make a display of a clock synchronous with the real time

Tags: javascript

I want to make a clock with javascript.

I want that the seconds and even milliseconds are displayed in real time, like a real clock. That you can see how the numbers are changing in real time.

I thought about a loop where a function is calling itself to repeat the write command like this one

```
function countdown (i) {
  if (i == undefined) {
    i = 10;
  }

  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
    var timeout = window.setTimeout("document.getElementById("thedate").innerHTML ... , 1000);
  }
}
countdown();
```

And how can I make it that the function is repeating itself in the same speed like the real clock, is this even possible?

When I just set the step intervall of setTimeout at 1 and repeat the function 1000 times per second it is maybe asynchronous with the real time I defined before by getDate, am I right?

The main question is: how can I get my repeating function synchron with the real time?

Comment: Have you looked into the `setInterval()` function? I think that's what you need here: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html

Comment: Also, it's probably better to pass an actual anonymous function to `setTimeout()` rather than a string of code

Comment: setTimeout() doesn't let you do 1000 per second: if you pass it a delay less than 4ms it automatically rounds it up to 4ms. In any case the delay isn't guaranteed, so for an accurate clock you need to get the time again from a Date object in every timeout.

Comment: neither setTimeout nor setInterval is guaranteed to execute at the exact moment that you expect them to. Check out http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setInterval` Web Api for that problem:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 1000);

function myCallback() {
  // Gets called every second
}
```

[Documentation for the setInterval() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

In my blog , you can find exactly what you want

http://turgaygulmez.com/javascript-local-time/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating infinite loop with function, just use `setInterval(function () {}, 1000);`